# Infra red light C#

Tags: c#, webcam, light, infrared

Using c#, How can I identify infra red light (that my webcam would see).  Will the necessary code differ depending on the make and model of my webcam?

Comment: Thank you, I thought there should be a way to see light, just any light, (it'd better if I could distinguish between light and bright light, but...).

Answer (score 1):

A webcam can see a little IR and you can make it see more by [removing the IR filter](http://www.instructables.com/id/Infrared-IR-Webcam/step5/Find-the-filter/) but it can only report it as... Red.

The whole chain of definition(s) of colour is aimed at the visual spectrum, only containing RGB values. You will see the IR as a 'false colour'.

Comment: I'm OK with a bool or "Red" ad an output.

Comment: So how would that work exactly?  Is there some example code I can find somewhere?

Comment: No, there is no code. Neither the PC hardware nor any software graphics API will recognize/support IR.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer 100% (sorry)  IR is 100% visible to cameras.  Hold a TV remote up to your webcam, you'll see what I mean  or just look [here](http://i.imgur.com/5liZI.jpg). That light is invisible to me